# How does this while(true) loop ever exit?

Tags: java, while-loop

```
package hi;

import java.util.Scanner;

class hi {

    /**
     * www.instanceofjava.com
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a binary number: ");

        int binarynum = in.nextInt();
        int binary = binarynum;

        int decimal = 0;
        int power = 0;

        while (true) {

            if (binary == 0) {

                break;

            } else {

                int tmp = binary % 10;
                decimal += tmp * Math.pow(2, power);
                binary = binary / 10;
                power++;

            }
        }
        System.out.println("while is false");
        System.out.println("Binary=" + binary + " Decimal=" + decimal);

    }
}
```

I can't understand how the while loop ends. When will the condition in `while` become `false`?

Comment: You might want to read up on what the [`break` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to exit a loop:

1. Through the condition in the loop's head to evaluate to false.
2. With a branch statement, specifically with `break` or `return`.

In your case the condition in the loop's head is always `true`, hence this will never cause the loop to exit.

However you have a `break` statement, which is executed as soon as `binary == 0` evaluates to `true`. `break` will exit the loop.

You might want to read up on [branch statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html).

Answer (score 0):

In every iteration you are reducing your binary number by dividing it by `10`. So, ultimately after certain iterations the value of binary becomes `0`. Since, you are using the condition at the beginning of each iteration:

```
if (binary == 0) {

    break;

}
```

the loop here terminates because of the `break` statement in it.

Comment: OP is asking why the while loop ever ends, because OP probably doesn't understand what `break` does. This doesn't answer OPs question, your code improvement merely hides away what OP is trying to understand, still leaving them in the dark. This leads to cargo cult programming.

Comment: Oops..my bad . Corrected it now

Comment: No worries. I actually think that your refactoring is still valuable as an addition after explaining OPs question.